Tab link issue: Occasionally, the link does not function properly
I experienced an issue—the tab works almost 90% of the time, which brings you to that content. Sometimes, the clickable tab brings me to the home page. Can someone please tell me why he is doing that? This is my code:
 <ul class="nav flex-column nav-pills brand-pills" id="myTab" role="tablist">
            <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link active" id="ultrasonic-Cleaning-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#ultrasonic-Cleaning" role="tab" aria-controls="ultrasonic-Cleaning" aria-selected="true">Category 1</a>
              <hr>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link " id="robotic-Hydroblasting-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#robotic-Hydroblasting" role="tab" aria-controls="robotic-Hydroblasting" aria-selected="true">Category 2</a>
              <hr>
            </li>
                     
            <li class="dropdown"> <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Category 3</a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link " id="straight-Tube-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#straight-Tube" role="tab" aria-controls="straight-Tube" aria-selected="true">Straight Tube </a></li>
               </ul>
              <hr>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown"> <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Category 4<span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link " id="scaffolding-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#scaffolding" role="tab" aria-controls="scaffolding" aria-selected="true">Scaffolding </a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link " id="column-Internals-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#column-Internals" role="tab" aria-controls="column-Internals" aria-selected="true">Column Internals </a></li>
 
              </ul>
              <hr>
            </li>
              
      <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link " id="a-complete-solution-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#a-complete-solution" role="tab" aria-controls="a-complete-solution" aria-selected="true">Category 5</a>
              <hr>
            </li>
          </ul>

When uploading the page live, I suspect there was some interference. I am still determining what it is. If the loading still needs to be finished, then I click too quickly. It didn't go as planned, but it went to the home page. What triggers this?
Here's what the vertical tab look like:

